# Issues with mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, installation, connection

Guys pls have a look at this code:
Been struggling with this for the past 12 hours but still have no idea what could be wrong. apparently it has issues with mongodb.connect and throws the error: TypeError: mongodb.connect is not a function

mongodb is istalled:

npm install express.
npm install mogodb.
npm link mongodb.
npm init -y.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmTir.png)
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GraVM.png)

Comment: please provide some more info regarding the question, some minimum  sample reproducable code.

Comment: See the [MongoDB NodeJS QuickStart](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/quick-start/) for installation and connecting examples.

Comment: for code sample there are 2 screenshots attached: "code" and  "package.json"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use mongoose ODM. To solve this simply install mongoose using npm => `npm i mongoose` and connect to your URL using mongoose.connect. Here is an example of how I use it in my projects.Also do not forget to import it first.
https://prnt.sc/1bc7yf3
Also I found this doc that connects to client using Mongodb itself and is similar to your approach and I think this may help you out https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/tutorials/commands/

Comment: still not working. this time it throws other errors.

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the errors it is throwing? Also I found this article that connects to client using Mongodb itself and is similar to your approach and I think this may help you out [https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/tutorials/commands/](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/tutorials/commands/)

Comment: Please approve/upvote answer if you found it helpful or it helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks. I finally made this possible by using this code:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
let assert = require('assert')
let url = "myour mongo link"

app.use(express.static("public")) 
MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function (err, client){
    db = client.db()
    app.listen(3000)
})
```